# Opening a MS Access database as read only without locking it

Tags: database, file, ms-access, locking, readonly

I opened in MS Access a *.mdb file, stating explicitly I wanted to open it as read only in the open file dialog box. Now, I tried to do changes in another place and they always fail to save to the database because MS Access has locked it, as I verified it created a *.ldb file near the *.mdb file.

Is there a way MS Access can open the file as read only without locking it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'changes in another place' - what other place? An ldb is always created when db opens, read only or not. This is not a split db?

Comment: @June7 What is a split db?

Comment: Well, you should Google the topic. And I just learned that opening db as Exclusive Read Only does not create locking file but it also does not help your situation. What kind of changes do you mean - data or design?

Comment: @June7 Ok, done. [Split an Access database](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/split-an-access-database-3015ad18-a3a1-4e9c-a7f3-51b1d73498cc) I didn't know Access had this feature.Changes I will do elsewhere are data.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can't do that.

Any [ACID compliant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) database requires locking, and since an Access database is just a file, locking requires writing.

In contrast to SQL server, Access has no `NOLOCK` hints or `READ UNCOMMITED` isolation to perform ACID incompliant dirty reads.

Even if you mark a file as read-only and reads are unsupported, the LDB file is still created.

You can, of course, address this at the filesystem level, for example by copying the file upon access and working with that copy. Some network file systems allow copy on write, allowing you to have multiple users access the same file, but only commit one version.

Of course, if the file is read-only but lockable, the alternative is opening the file in read-only exclusive mode. That won't generate a LDB, and won't cause conflicts or corrupt reads as all writes by all users are denied. But it won't allow any actions by other users.